# sql server DATEADD with sql inside DATEADD

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to do the following:

```
    Select ProID from Pros ps where ps.ProId = '102-C01-1299'
    and  ConfirmDate > DATEADD(DAY, (select tt.DaysDue from tblTaskTimeline tt where Task   = 'TaskInfo') as days,ps.ProgStartDate)
```

Note how for the DATEADD function, I need to dynamically get the 2nd parameter.
Note that tt.DaysDue returns an integer value.

I get a message saying that DATEADD requires 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove " as days" and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a parameter first?

```
declare @days int
set @days = (select tt.DaysDue from tblTaskTimeline tt where Task   = 'TaskInfo')

Select ProID 
from Pros ps 
where ps.ProId = '102-C01-1299'
    and  ConfirmDate > DATEADD(DAY, @days, ps.ProgStartDate)
```

If you cannot use a parameter then the following should work:

```
Select ProID 
from Pros ps 
where ps.ProId = '102-C01-1299'
    and  ConfirmDate > DATEADD(DAY, (select tt.DaysDue from tblTaskTimeline tt where Task = 'TaskInfo'), ps.ProgStartDate)
```

Comment: Because this is part of a larger sql statement in which case I need to do it in 'one shot'